# Loosing observation when I use reshape in R

Tags: r, matrix, reshape

I have data set

```
> head(pain_subset2, n= 50)
     PatientID RSE SE SECODE
1    1001-01   0  0      0
2    1001-01   0  0      0
3    1001-02   0  0      0
4    1001-02   0  0      0
5    1002-01   0  0      0
6    1002-01   1 2a      1
7    1002-02   0  0      0
8    1002-02   0  0      0
9    1002-02   0  0      0
10   1002-03   0  0      0
11   1002-03   0  0      0
12   1002-03   1  1      1

> dim(pain_subset2)
[1] 817   4
> table(pain_subset2$RSE)
  0   1 
788  29 
> table(pain_subset2$SE)
  0   1  2a  2b   3   4   5 
788   7   5   1   6   4   6 
> table(pain_subset2$SECODE)
  0   1 
788  29
```

I want to create matrix with n * 6 (n :# of PatientID, column :6 levels of SE)
I use reshape, I lost many observations

```
> dim(p)
[1] 246   9
```

My code:

```
p <- reshape(pain_subset2, timevar = "SE", idvar =  c("PatientID","RSE"),v.names = "SECODE", direction = "wide")
p[is.na(p)] <- 0
> table(p$RSE)
  0   1 
226  20
```

Compare with table of RSE, I lost 9 patients having 1.

This is out put I have

```
    PatientID RSE SECODE.0 SECODE.2a SECODE.1 SECODE.5 SECODE.3 SECODE.2b  SECODE.4
1     1001-01   0        0         0        0        0        0         0           0
3     1001-02   0        0         0        0        0        0         0        0
5     1002-01   0        0         0        0        0        0         0        0
6     1002-01   1        0         1        0        0        0         0        0
7     1002-02   0        0         0        0        0        0         0        0
10    1002-03   0        0         0        0        0        0         0        0
12    1002-03   1        0         0        1        0        0         0        0
13    1002-04   0        0         0        0        0        0         0        0
15    1003-01   0        0         0        0        0        0         0        0
18    1003-02   0        0         0        0        0        0         0        0
21    1003-03   0        0         0        0        0        0         0        0
24    1003-04   0        0         0        0        0        0         0        0
27    1003-05   0        0         0        0        0        0         0        0
30    1003-06   0        0         0        0        0        0         0        0
32    1003-07   0        0         0        0        0        0         0        0
35    1004-01   0        0         0        0        0        0         0        0
36    1004-01   1        0         0        0        1        0         0        0
40   1004-02a   0        0         0        0        0        0         0        0
```

Anyone knows what happens, I really appreciate.
Thanks for your help, best.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

pain_subset2 %>%
  spread(SE, SECODE)
```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it, it's correct now, I add 1 more variable idvar =  c("PatientID","Eval",RSE"), so make it unique, I got total dimension

Comment: @Stat haha, glad you figured it out :)

Comment: Still can't figure the best way to create matrix

Comment: `p` is a data frame. Please, try `as.matrix(p[, -(1:2)])` to coerce all but the first two columns of `p`.

Comment: I mean not using reshape, matrix will be only 1 and 0, if SE has 2a, or 2b, or 1 , 6 levels, set 1, if not set 0, I use reshape and then I have to collase data so I get only unique patient for each row